# ReactNativeのIOSシミュレータの立ち上げについて

Tags: xcode, react-native

既存のリポジトリにあるReactNativeプロジェクトをローカル環境で触れるように環境構築中です。

リポジトリをクローンした後、「npm install」「pod install」は終わったのですがシミュレータを立ち上げることができません。
xcodeを確認したところ、以下のエラー分が表示されます。

```
"could not find node. It looks like that the .xcode.env or .xcode.env.local
```

これは自分がnodebrewを使用しているためだと推測しているのですが、どのような設定が必要なのでしょうか？